# Using PhantomJS, Electron, NWJS or AppJS as a wallpaper engine for Mac OS X, Linux and Windows

Tags: html, node.js, browser, desktop, wallpaper

I have recently discovered the Mac OS X application `GeekTool` where one can use a html file as your wallpaper. However that isnt the most interesting thing, what I find interesting about it is that it keeps the html file alive even allowing http requests. I wanted to create that using Node.js and some other web technology that allows to run a browser on the desktop with full access to nodejs' APIs.

So I wondered if there is any way to create an alive browser in the background (as a wallpaper), which is interactive (e.g. I can press buttons and type in inputs). If so, where can read about that?

I prefer either one of the packages mentioned above, but others are accepted as well. What I need it to do is just being under the desktop-icons but as well over the default wallpaper, so it can be interactive.

Thanks